# Xcode 6.1.1 with GCC cannot change build options

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, gcc

Working on ios development project, from code provided, using c++ in Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite 10.10. LLVM leads to various compilation errors. Want to use GCC instead. Been poking around for some direction got a start but now I am stuck.

Downloaded GCC, version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

Tried to add the path to compile with under Xcode but failed.

Edited .bash_profile to utilize these export paths and aliases.

    `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
    export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp-4.2
    export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2
    alias gcc="gcc-4.2"
    alias g++="g++-4.2"`

Also installed command line tools using `xcode-select --install`.

When I run `xcrun gcc --version` I get 
`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix`

Relatively new user to the mac world, but am learning on the fly. Not sure why I cannot select compile with GCC 4.2.1 from the build settings after trying to get this set. Any help would be appreciated.